# UNIX Timestamp in future mysql

Tags: mysql, unix

I have a table that holds a few UNIX timestamps that are in the future, I need to find the ones that are older than `NOW()` or are within 10 minutes of being in the past.

Here's the query I have tried using to no avail

```
SELECT 
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(`expires`))) AS `time_diff` 
FROM 
    `video_table`
WHERE
    time_diff < NOW() OR time_diff > '-600'
```

Can anyone point me in the direction as to why this will not work?

Comment: Wouldn't timestamps that are in the past now  also be in the past in 10 minutes' time?

Comment: @Strawberry yes, but I need to catch them before they expire so I can renew them before hand

Comment: I think you're missing my point - or else I'm missing yours!

Comment: @Strawberry - the timestamps that are stored in the `expires` column are in the future, I just need to find ones are in between now and 10 minutes from the current time `NOW() + 10 MINS`

Comment: Anyway, you can't use an alias in this way. Choices include switching to HAVING, writing the diff out longhand, or maybe something slightly better still

Comment: You can't refer to a column alias in the `WHERE` clause of the same query. You need to use `HAVING` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not too clear, but I'm trying to answer with a few scenarios.

This query will return all records already expired:

```
SELECT * FROM video_table WHERE expires < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

And this will return all records that are about to expire (they will expire within 10 minutes):

```
SELECT * FROM video_table
WHERE expires>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AND expires<UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 600
```

This will return all records in the future (they will expire later than 10 minutes from now):

```
SELECT * FROM video_table WHERE expires>UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 600
```

Answer (score 1):

`time_diff` will give you the difference between `NOW()` and your `expires` column. What you want is to actually check if `NOW()`<`expires` (`time_diff` < 0) or if it's (NOW()+600s < expires) (`time_diff` < 600). So it's enough to check the latter:

```
SELECT 
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(`expires`))) AS `time_diff` 
FROM 
    `video_table`
HAVING
    `time_diff` < 600
```

Comment: Sorry, changed WHERE to HAVING.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,expires INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table(expires) VALUES
(1442075399), 
(1442075499), 
(1442075599), 
(1442075699), 
(1442076106),
(1442076206),
(1442076306),
(1442076406);

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
+------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP() |
+------------------+
|       1442075727 |
+------------------+

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE expires - 600 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
+----+------------+
| id | expires    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 1442075399 |
|  2 | 1442075499 |
|  3 | 1442075599 |
|  4 | 1442075699 |
|  5 | 1442076106 |
|  6 | 1442076206 |
|  7 | 1442076306 |
+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE_ADD` to get a time in the future:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - `expires` AS `time_diff` 
FROM `video_table`
WHERE expires < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand what you  are trying to do, if you create a variable that will give the present time and than run your query as a less than or equal to clause it should work.
 Here is an example

```
$t=time();

SELECT * FROM video_table
WHERE column_holding_unix_time<=$t;
```

I hope this helps